# The best way to track method invocation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript, and I am now given a project that used Javascript heavily. In most of the JS files, it will contain statements of the following format:

```
 Jebber.Ajax.enqueueAction(smsType, true, options, callback);
```

I am familiar with Java, so I assume there might be some import or sth. at the top of the file, but there isn't any, and there is no explicit definition of "Jebber" variable. So I am curious about where does this Jebber variable come from. I am using Eclipse to edit the JavaScript files, it seems F3 doesn't work to retrieve the definition of a method.

So I am a little bit stuck here:could experts teach me a good way to dive through a large collection of JavaScript files to find the definition of variables/functions etc.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open Chrome Dev Tools > Resources Tab > Search "Jebber" it will tell you which `.js` file has the definition.

Comment: @MrCode: doesn't it search only through the opened file?

Comment: @zerkms it searches all Javascript files that are included and also any inline Javascript that resides within HTML. Firebug has the same ability on the Script tab.

Comment: @MrCode: oh I see now - confused *Re*sources and Sources, didn't know that! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using [JS Object setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'Jebber', {
    set: function() {
        debugger;
    },
    get: function() {} 
});
```

When something is assigned to a global `Jebber` variable you'll get a break in a js debugger (use the one in chrome dev tools for example)

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XtZkJ/

Open debugger and see on the stack trace - it will point to the exact line the variable modified.

Comment: @Alnitak: when you're debugging code - you may put anything in the beginning of the execution process.

Comment: @Sam: not sure and it doesn't matter - it is supposed to be used just for debugging purposes. And for that OP may use the most recent software.

Comment: right, so you're looking to create a break point at the first point that `Window.Jebber` is defined.  I somehow think the OP is going to struggle with that if he doesn't know that JS has _page_ scope, not `.js` file scope.

Comment: @Alnitak: from what I understood - OP wants to find a place where the variable is defined. Though the question isn't completely clear, so it's partially my guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

The "import" will be `<script>` tags within the *HTML* file, not the script file.